# How to update JToken value

Tags: .net

I need to **implement a function which is updating a value**` in Jtoken:

```
public  object SetValue(JToken token, string[] pos,string value)
```

It should basically do:

```
token[pos[0]][pos[1]][pos[2]]....[pos[n]] = value;
```

I did the following:

```
public  object SetValue(JToken token, string[] pos,string value)
{

      JToken Token = token;
      foreach (string pos in position)
      {
        Token = Token[pos];
      }
      Token = value;
      return token.ToString();
}
```

The string being returned is not updated with the val, Can you point me what I did wrong or how to better implement this function ?

Thanks.

Comment: Does it even run? You accept input `pos`, yet in foreach you iterate over `position` and assign to `pos`. Where does `position` even come from? `Token` is empty, because you just created it. Then you override entire `Token` with value `Token` is supposed to contain at `pos`. Then you return string representation of `token` without doing anything to it.

Comment: public  object SetValue(JToken token, string[] position,string value)
{

      JToken Token = token;
      foreach (string pos in position)
      {
        Token = Token[pos];
      }
      Token = value;
      return token.ToString();
}

Comment: Typo , This is fixed code:

Comment: JToken token = JObject.Parse(_data); -> Then I call the function: SetValue(token, new string[] { "a","b"} , "val");

Answer (score 0):

Names in C# are case sensitive, so `token` and `Token` refer to different things. Your code was working on `Token` without ever touching `token` and then returning `token`.

I believe code below should do what you're trying to achieve.

```
public object SetValue(JToken token, string[] position, string value)
{    
    JToken Token = token;

    foreach (string pos in position)
    {
        Token[pos] = value;
    }

    return Token.ToString();
}
```

I would suggest few improvements from here:

- Avoid using return type `object`. Be more specific if you can. If you mean to return `token` have return type `JToken`, if you mean to return `token.ToString()`, then have return type `string`;
- It's a convention to use camelCase for names of local variables in C#;
- You can use `var` instead of full name of a type like `JToken` if you assign value in same statement as you declare a variable. Static code analyzers suggest using `var`.

Same function changed to above suggestions would look like this:

```
public string SetValue(JToken token, string[] positions, string value)
{    
    var jtoken = token;

    foreach (var pos in positions)
    {
        jtoken[pos] = value;
    }

    return jtoken.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I don't think that your code implements what I needed... I only need the LAST item in positions array to be assigned with the value : token[pos[0]][pos[1]][pos[2]]....[pos[n]] = value;